# How to json data to data table in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I getting data from server side. Like this

```
         var data="page="+pageno;
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"php/totalDevices.php",
            data:data,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data) {
            json_obj=data;
            createTable(json_obj); // function Calling for create Table
            },
             error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             console.log(errorThrown);
             },
             complete: function(){
                $('#loader_totalDevices').hide();
            }

        });
```

How to add this data to Data Table

Comment: show JSON data as well as table???

Comment: json = ["devices":{name:"", "id":""},{..},{..},"pages":""].

Comment: add in your question, what you exact mean **data to Data Table**? can you please elaborate

Comment: I want to call server page with page numbe. IN server side get all information and send back to client. and that data will show in data table